# Covering hot outlet and waterline

Tags: electrical, plumbing

Can I cover up a wall outlet and water line to an old icemaker with a drawer base cabinet? Or do I need to cut out the back of the cabinet to allow access?

Answer (score 1):

You should cut out the back of the cabinet.

Answer (score 0):

There is no safety reason to do so. So, if you do not need the outlet feel free to block it.

Code typically requires outlets every so-and-so many feet along a wall, but this is a convenience requirement, not a safety requirement. If you find it more convenient to have the cabinet there and do not care about the outlet, then there is no legal requirement that you leave it exposed.

A future owner of the home may have different ideas, but by that time your cabinet will be long gone.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you can still get to the outlet.

OPTION 1 : If the cabinet can be moved than it's fine. Electricians know to move things and look for plugs when problems occur. Therefore its accessible.

OPTION 2: If its a permanent cabinet, Cut out the back of the drawer.

In Canada that is a code requirement and generally in America , your code out does our code, so you can bet that you need it accessible in America.

Its more to do with the fact that things go wrong with circuits randomly, or circuits get moved and changed and if an electrician can't find a box it can be a real problem. Basically when figuring things out if there are two wires that you have no clue where they go, it can be hard.

That being said its not a safety issue. So don't loose sleep.

OPTION 3: Is this the last plug on the circuit (no splices to other boxes occur in this box you want to hide?) If it is the last circuit and super annoying to keep the box assessable than I might go to where that outlet box is fed from (maybe another box), open it up, disconnect the wires to the plug I wanna cover (and put wire nuts on them) and write on electrical tape in that box where the wire goes. (Feeds to behind the such and such cabinet).

Thats what I would do!